# Multicast peer does not receiving datagram packet from particular peer in Java

Tags: java, p2p, datagram

I am trying to develop a simple application where multiple peer join into multicast service, one of the peer ask some question and those peer which has answer for that question should response to peer which asked question. 
After joining to multicast, one peer ask question as

```
String query = receptionPort + " " + txtQuestion.getText();
InetAddress groupAddress = InetAddress.getByName(228.5.6.7);
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(query.getBytes(), query.length(), groupAddress, 6789);
```

And this peer has reception port 6859(different than group port-6789 on which all peer joined)

All peers joined on that group port receive this question, and among those one have answer and send answer to peer that has asked question like this:

```
DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
InetAddress groupAddress = InetAddress.getByName(228.5.6.7);
DatagramPacket answerPacket = new DatagramPacket(answerByte, answerByte.length, groupAddress, 6859);
datagramSocket.send(answerPacket);
```

And in question asked peer, this will receive like this (which is not working)

```
byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket receivePacket;
receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
DatagramSocket =new DatagramSocket(6859);
datagramSocket.receive(receivePacket);
```

Anyone please help. While using multicasting, how one peer send udp datagram to another particular one peer using separate UDP communication.

Comment: Why are you using two ports when one would do? Don't waste ports. They are a finite resource. Anyway if you must, you need to create the receiving socket on that port before sending the request. Otherwise you could be too late and miss the reply.

Comment: According to requirement, we need separate UDP connection to send answer to peer who have asked question. And for this there are one group port and one reception port.

Comment: 'According to requirement' doesn't answer my question. It just handballs it somewhere else. There is no necessity for this in UDP. And if you hadn't had this 'requirement' you wouldn't have had this problem.

Comment: Yeah I agree. But  this is the specification on my assignment. I have created receiving socket before sending question to peers. But still question asked peer didn't receive the answer packet.